# How to recreate an element in Threepenny GUI?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

If I use the `delete` function on some `Element`s, how can I then recreate them (as in make them appear again)?

I have looked around the examples and documentation, but I couldn't find any function that would allow me to do this except maybe `mkElement` which requires me to pass it a `String`. However since I'm working with `Element`s getting the `String` that would create it would be a bit difficult.

So is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Library author here)

Actually the, `delete` function does more than just remove the element from the DOM tree — it tries to delete any references to it in the JS and Haskell side. Essentially the element is (should be) unuseable after a `delete`.

If you want to temporarily hide an element, you can

- Hide it via the CSS `display` property.
- Rest the children of the parent element, e.g. by `element parent # set children []`.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realize it worked that way. I'll fix that then. Would be good to put that into the documentation though, since it doesn't make it clear that they shouldn't be usable after `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `delete` has the signature `delete :: Element -> UI ()`, it follows that when you call `delete`, you have an `Element` in hand. Why can't you just hold onto this `Element` somewhere? (By which I mean maintain a reference to it in any number of ways.) Then just use `(#+) :: UI Element -> [UI Element] -> UI Element` to attach it as a child to another element later. If you just want it to reappear where it was before, you'd just attach it as a child to the very element that was its parent to begin with. Is this what you had in mind, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot to try putting it as child elements to show them again. That works.